# Inserting date from mysql into a table html

Tags: mysql

I have the following question, 
I have a mysql table with the following columns,

```
-name
-address
-zipcode
-etc.
```

I have in my php code a table like this:

```
<table class="listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th>Company name</th>
                    <th>Adress</th>
                    <th>Zipcode</th>
                    <th>more</th>
                    <th>more</th>

                    <th>more</th>
                    <th>more</th>
                    <th>more</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

What I want is that when someone creates a company that it will display a row with the data from mysql so just like this:

Company               address             zipcode
1                                   1                              1
2                                    2                              2

Can someone help me?

edit:

Some extra code:

```
    <div id="center-column">
      <div class="select-bar">
               Bedrijven:
            </div>
            <div class="table">
                <table class="listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company name</th>
                        <th>Adress</th>
                        <th>Zipcode</th>
                        <th>more</th>
                        <th>more</th>

                        <th>more</th>
                        <th>more</th>
                        <th>more</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="table">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-column">
            <strong class="h">Info</strong>
            <div class="box"><strong>Gebruikersnaam:</strong> <?php echo $naam ?><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php else : ?>
```

Comment: What have you got so for at to your `mysql` query? Note: mysql is deprecated, take a look at `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code: 
(change to your needs: localhost, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW)

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','DATABASE_NAME');
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
$sql = "USE DATABASE_NAME";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)
    or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

echo "<table border='0'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . 'Company: ' . "<b>" . $row['TABLE_ROW'] . "</b>" . ' | Address: ' . "<b>" . $row ['TABLE_ROW'] . "</b>" . ' | Zipcode: ' . "<b>" . $row ['TABLE_ROW'] . "</b>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    } 
echo "</table>";
?>
```

If you have more questions or it doesn't work, please let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: Why `die`? Use propper error handling in stead. `Die` kills the script, any `html` below will not get rendered.

Comment: It would also be better to use `printf`. This increases readability.

Comment: @Remco Vijfschaft it still doesn't work, it doesn't displaying the data, And the script is already connected to mysql,

Comment: Show us some code @KevinKuijer, that was we can help you better